# Stripe test Webhooks on Production Server

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, backend, payment-gateway, webhooks

I'm currently testing the production server for my **stripe webhooks**.

Locally I purchased a Test-Product and listen for the webhook with the **stripe CLI** for my `localhost:5000/hooks`.

There everything worked as expected.

Now I deployed the server and I setup the live stripe webhook inside my **dashboard**.

But If I now purchase a Test-Product, my webhook on my production server does not execute.

Does someone know what's the reason for this?

How can I test the live webhook without spending money for the Live-Products?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: In most cases you would follow https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/go-live and do any actual testing in test mode rather than "testing again" in live mode.